Injection fails when the action is triggered from a child component
Learning Angular 18, I am facing an unexpected behaviour: injection silently failing when an action is triggered by a child component, but ultimately it's defined in the parent component, where the injection fails.
child.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `
    <button type="button" (click)="action()">Navigate using child</button>
  `,
  styles: ``
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() action: () => void = () =>  {};
}

parent.component.ts
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from "../child/child.component";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  template: `
    <h1>Parent</h1>
    <app-child [action]="actionInParent" />
    <button type="button" (click)="actionInParent()">Navigate using parent</button>
  `,
  styles: ``
})
export class ParentComponent {
  private router = inject(Router)

  actionInParent() {
    console.log("Action invoked")
    this.router.navigateByUrl('child')
  }

}

app.routes.ts
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'parent', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'parent', component: ParentComponent },
    { path: 'child', component: ChildComponent }
];

If I press "Navigate using parent", navigation works. If I press "Navigate using child", navigation fails with this error:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '>>navigateByUrl')
at _ChildComponent.actionInParent [as action] (parent.component.ts:20:17)
at ChildComponent_Template_button_click_0_listener (child.component.ts:8:36)
at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:25797:12)
at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.mjs:25829:18)
at HTMLButtonElement. (platform-browser.mjs:745:112)
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:33)
at core.mjs:6717:49
at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:6717:30)
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:38)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:7037:25)


Please share the routes config and the error message

Why are you not using an output for this ?

@BennyHalperin edited and added routes and error message

@MatthieuRiegler not sure to understand what you mean with using output, sorry

https://angular.dev/guide/components/outputs

@MatthieuRiegler nailed! Thanks. If you want you can write an answer

import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from "../child/child.component";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  template: `
    <h1>Parent</h1>
    <app-child [action]="actionInParent" />
    <button type="button" (click)="actionInParent()">Navigate using parent</button>
  `,
  styles: ``
})
export class ParentComponent {
  private router = inject(Router)

  actionInParent = () => {
    console.log("Action invoked")
    this.router.navigateByUrl('child')
  }

}

